# What does the following c++ code return?

Tags: c++, types, dictionary, iterator, unordered-map

I have a piece of code to be understood. But I'm lost in one point.
Here is the code:

```
typedef unordered_map <string, TimeStampSet *> HIEMap;
typedef set <TimeStamp> TimeStampSet;

struct HostInfo {
    HostActivity *hostActivity;
    HIEMap *hieMapArr;
};

typedef unordered_map <uint32_t, HostInfo *> HostInfoMap;

HIEMap::iterator hieMapIt;

void method(...){
    for (hieMapIt = hostInfoIt -> second -> hieMapArr -> begin();
         hieMapIt != hostInfoIt -> second -> hieMapArr -> end();
         hieMapIt = nextMapIt)
    {
        if (hieMapIt -> second == NULL) {
           //what does *hieMapIt -> second* returns?
        }
    }
}
```

What does `hieMapIt -> second` return?  I' m a bit lost.

This is not all code, there are initializations and so on. But I dont put all the code here.

Thanks,

Comment: Roll back the edit and open a new question. You can delete this question if you think it wasn't appropriate, but you may want to consider leaving it and accepting an answer if you think people's time was well spent on you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will return a `TimeStampSet *`. That is, the second part of the unordered_map (string , TimeStampSet *) "pair".

Comment: @tusherity That is inappropriate. Don't completely change your question when you've gotten several good answers.

Comment: I see your point but I guess I got tired so I asked that question :( I know that is not true, sorry about that

Comment: I rolled your question back to its original. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing an iterator of a container gives you an object whose type is the `value_type` of the container. For a `map<K, T>` (or `unordered_map`), the `value_type` is `pair<K const, T>`, so that you can use `it->first` and `it->second` to access the key and mapped value of the map element.

So `hostInfoIt->second` is a `HostInfo *`,  `...->hieMapArr` is a `HIEMap *`, and `hieMapIt` is a `HIEMap::iterator`. Thus `hieMapIt->second` is a `TimeStampSet *`.

Comment: @tusherity: Now it's a completely different question. I'm not gonna [play that game](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). Post a new question if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

An [`std::unordered_map<K,V>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) contains [`std::pair<const K,V>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), so dereferencing an iterator to an element of such a map element gives you a handle on one of those. And `std::pair<const K,V>::second` is a `V`, which in your case is a pointer to `TimeStampSet`